# dual index loops in R

Tags: r, loops, indexing

For coding aficionados this may be a no-brainer but as someone new to these tools it's been twisting my noodle for a while now.

Essentially I have some chemometric data that I wish to adjust against a series of blanks run at intervals through the sample analysis.  All the outputs are time stamped and I want to use the proportional ratio of the interval between the sample and the next blank over the interval between two successive blanks, plus the last blank value, as a modifier for a simple interpolation of the correction factor applied.  When the sample time value is later than the second blank I want to increment the blank pair so that I'm applying a correction based on the new pair of blanks for samples that fall in between their time periods.
My data set contains a range of elements and the blank corrections differ between elements.

Data set:

```
Blanks
   Sample           Date/Time Location Li(ppb) Mg(ppb) Ca(ppm) Cr(ppb) Mn(ppb) Co(ppb) Ni(ppb) Cu(ppb) Zn(ppb) Rb(ppb) Sr(ppb) Cd(ppb) Ba(ppb) Ce(ppb) Gd(ppb) Pb(ppb) U(ppb)
1  Blank0 2016-05-23 19:54:33        B   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000       0   0.000   0.000       0   0.000  0.000
7  Blank1 2016-05-23 20:35:25        B  -0.069   0.081   0.005  -0.007  -0.001   0.000  -0.007   0.005  -0.004   0.000   0.005       0  -0.003   0.000       0   0.000  0.005
18 Blank2 2016-05-23 21:50:30        B  -0.076   0.743   0.020  -0.005   0.002  -0.001  -0.008   0.002   0.220   0.001   0.042       0   0.008   0.002       0   0.002  0.000
29 Blank3 2016-05-23 23:05:43        B  -0.093  -0.080   0.000  -0.020  -0.001  -0.001  -0.010   0.001  -0.009   0.000  -0.001       0   0.001   0.000       0   0.000  0.000
38 Blank4 2016-05-24 00:07:19        B  -0.096  -0.045   0.000  -0.015   0.000  -0.001  -0.001  -0.002   0.002   0.000  -0.001       0   0.000   0.000       0   0.000  0.000
```

Data: Mdat_samp

```
     Sample           Date/Time Location Li(ppb) Mg(ppb) Ca(ppm) Cr(ppb) Mn(ppb) Co(ppb) Ni(ppb) Cu(ppb) Zn(ppb) Rb(ppb) Sr(ppb) Cd(ppb) Ba(ppb) Ce(ppb) Gd(ppb) Pb(ppb) U(ppb)
2  PK-Std1p 2016-05-23 20:01:22        S  -0.013  111.10   31.28   1.050   0.121   0.910   0.157   0.134   0.141   0.010   35.28   0.010   0.145   0.113   0.123   0.036  0.897
3  PK-Std2p 2016-05-23 20:08:10        S   0.018  216.60   41.17   5.095   0.491   4.654   0.294   0.533   0.511   0.048   71.03   0.047   0.500   0.456   0.240   0.081  4.497
4  PK-Std3p 2016-05-23 20:14:59        S   0.057  303.90   48.90   9.695   1.215   9.332   0.487   1.294   1.180   0.093  105.30   0.093   1.164   1.128   0.467   0.132  9.057
5  PK-Std4p 2016-05-23 20:21:48        S   0.234  391.80   57.01  14.060   4.903  14.100   0.704   5.100   4.597   0.239  141.40   0.231   4.583   4.556   0.703   0.965 13.730
6  PK-Std5p 2016-05-23 20:28:36        S   0.477  474.20   64.35  29.560   9.621  30.050   0.908   9.985   9.030   0.467  173.20   0.459   8.909   8.956   0.913   4.506 29.350
8       L1W 2016-05-23 20:42:14        L   0.037  141.90   33.48   0.003   0.714   0.020   0.113   0.200   0.217   0.007   72.64   0.001   0.125   0.008   0.001   0.037  0.012
9       L2W 2016-05-23 20:49:03        L   0.023  131.50   38.09  -0.003   0.590   0.014   0.106   0.134   0.694   0.004   75.96   0.001   0.115   0.008   0.001   0.031  0.008
10      L3W 2016-05-23 20:55:54        L   0.078  208.20   52.54  -0.002   0.843   0.021   0.153   0.180   0.119   0.005  110.40   0.002   0.172   0.011   0.001   0.054  0.009
11     L17W 2016-05-23 21:02:43        L   0.025  152.40   38.64  -0.008   0.658   0.016   0.117   0.270   0.121   0.006   82.45   0.001   0.108   0.008   0.001   0.042  0.007
12     L18W 2016-05-23 21:09:32        L   0.070  204.30   54.29  -0.005   1.311   0.023   0.172   0.417   0.197   0.008  117.00   0.002   0.144   0.010   0.001   0.057  0.010
13     L19W 2016-05-23 21:16:21        L   0.045  181.40   51.45  -0.004   0.701   0.020   0.162   0.296   0.160   0.008  109.20   0.001   0.116   0.009   0.001   0.055  0.009
14     L20W 2016-05-23 21:23:09        L   0.022  150.30   38.55   0.000   0.596   0.016   0.118   0.223   0.148   0.007   77.44   0.001   0.114   0.007   0.001   0.048  0.006
15     L21W 2016-05-23 21:29:59        L   0.010  132.70   34.72  -0.006   0.679   0.014   0.110   0.249   0.153   0.007   67.33   0.001   0.098   0.008   0.001   0.034  0.007
16     L23W 2016-05-23 21:36:49        L   0.035  210.00   48.16   0.006   1.230   0.020   0.155   0.370   0.202   0.008  110.20   0.001   0.251   0.012   0.001   0.055  0.010
17     L24W 2016-05-23 21:43:39        L   0.051  193.00   56.83   0.024   0.825   0.024   0.189   0.404   0.205   0.007  113.80   0.002   0.135   0.010   0.001   0.044  0.010
19      N1W 2016-05-23 21:57:20        N   0.041  205.10   49.06   0.005   1.077   0.021   0.157   0.481   0.143   0.006  102.90   0.002   0.145   0.012   0.001   0.049  0.012
20      N4W 2016-05-23 22:04:10        N  -0.002  140.90   38.72   0.008   0.887   0.016   0.131   0.312   0.130   0.005   76.39   0.001   0.133   0.010   0.001   0.032  0.011
21      N7W 2016-05-23 22:11:00        N   0.005  134.40   40.92   0.002   0.651   0.019   0.136   0.204   0.122   0.005   90.48   0.002   0.158   0.010   0.001   0.034  0.012
22     N10W 2016-05-23 22:17:50        N   0.010  150.10   40.86  -0.001   0.714   0.018   0.132   0.199   0.089   0.004   81.78   0.001   0.149   0.010   0.001   0.029  0.012
23     N11W 2016-05-23 22:24:40        N   0.028  156.10   43.10  -0.007   0.870   0.019   0.139   0.292   0.099   0.005   89.83   0.001   0.134   0.010   0.001   0.034  0.009
24     N12W 2016-05-23 22:31:31        N   0.015  158.60   43.03   0.019   0.807   0.018   0.145   0.253   0.113   0.006   87.60   0.001   0.117   0.011   0.001   0.039  0.009
25     N13W 2016-05-23 22:38:21        N   0.021  157.50   44.94   0.038   0.833   0.020   0.159   0.245   0.124   0.007   92.04   0.001   0.118   0.011   0.001   0.034  0.011
26     N14W 2016-05-23 22:45:12        N   0.041  171.80   49.04   0.008   1.115   0.020   0.165   0.226   0.123   0.006  109.00   0.002   0.177   0.011   0.001   0.044  0.010
27     N18W 2016-05-23 22:52:02        N   0.050  164.60   49.49   0.019   1.555   0.022   0.162   0.735   2.740   0.006  104.50   0.005   4.152   0.011   0.001   0.180  0.008
28     N23W 2016-05-23 22:58:52        N   0.001  132.30   36.21  -0.008   1.578   0.015   0.110   0.838   3.751   0.004   73.86   0.008   6.080   0.009   0.001   0.257  0.009
30     P10W 2016-05-23 23:12:33        P  -0.003  139.50   36.40  -0.005   0.537   0.018   0.123   0.334   0.172   0.005   76.07   0.002   0.127   0.008   0.001   0.033  0.008
31     P16W 2016-05-23 23:19:24        P   0.057  172.90   55.53  -0.003   0.689   0.025   0.186   0.253   0.482   0.004  124.10   0.001   0.122   0.010   0.001   0.041  0.010
32     P17W 2016-05-23 23:26:15        P   0.018  193.80   44.01   0.000   0.780   0.020   0.141   0.269   0.139   0.004   99.34   0.001   0.124   0.011   0.001   0.031  0.010
33     P19W 2016-05-23 23:33:06        P   0.040  181.50   51.98   0.027   0.762   0.026   0.173   0.320   0.191   0.008  108.70   0.002   0.162   0.011   0.001   0.043  0.009
34     P20W 2016-05-23 23:39:57        P   0.049  182.50   53.05   0.007   0.676   0.024   0.180   0.298   0.147   0.007  106.80   0.001   0.133   0.012   0.001   0.033  0.011
35     P21W 2016-05-23 23:46:48        P  -0.005  147.60   39.68   0.010   0.701   0.017   0.135   0.240   0.165   0.007   81.14   0.001   0.111   0.009   0.001   0.034  0.008
36     P22W 2016-05-23 23:53:39        P   0.008  181.40   41.83   0.031   0.789   0.026   0.157   0.604   0.295   0.010   92.27   0.002   0.172   0.015   0.002   0.032  0.017
37     P25W 2016-05-24 00:00:30        P  -0.016  124.30   31.92   0.028   0.596   0.015   0.104   0.265   0.187   0.004   64.91   0.002   0.080   0.008   0.001   0.049  0.007
39  PK-Std1 2016-05-24 00:14:07        S  -0.089   98.38   28.27   0.957   0.125   0.990   0.194   0.156   0.152   0.010   35.49   0.010   0.145   0.116   0.121   0.035  0.890
40  PK-Std2 2016-05-24 00:20:56        S  -0.041  198.80   38.35   4.812   0.504   4.968   0.338   0.570   0.527   0.049   71.38   0.051   0.503   0.465   0.237   0.080  4.520
41  PK-Std3 2016-05-24 00:27:45        S   0.012  289.00   46.70   9.434   1.245   9.890   0.555   1.383   1.227   0.094  105.40   0.094   1.191   1.138   0.472   0.134  9.091
42  PK-Std4 2016-05-24 00:34:34        S   0.166  383.40   56.11  13.920   5.029  14.930   0.771   5.473   4.775   0.241  143.00   0.239   4.623   4.637   0.707   0.962 14.120
43  PK-Std5 2016-05-24 00:41:22        S   0.427  462.20   63.08  29.060   9.831  31.610   0.972  10.650   9.258   0.475  174.30   0.461   8.977   9.092   0.916   4.532 29.790
```

My latest coding attempt is:

```
    j=1     
for (i in 1:nrow(Mdat_samp))
        {       
        divisor<-(as.double(difftime(Blanks[j+1, 2], Blanks[j,2]))-as.double(difftime(Blanks[j+1,2], Mdat_samp[i,2])))/as.double(difftime(Blanks[j+1, 2], Blanks[j,2])) 
        adjust<- (Blanks[j, 4:20]+(Blanks[j+1, 4:20]*divisor))
        write.table((Mdat_samp[i,4:20]-adjust), file="Baseadjust.txt", append=TRUE, col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, sep=",")
        if(as.double(difftime(Mdat_samp[j,2], Blanks[j,2]))<0) j=j+1
        if(j+1>nrow(Blanks)) break
        }
```

What doesn't seem to happen is for j to index properly so I end up applying the same correction to all subsequent lines rather than calculating and applying the correction for the specific line.  As I see it I have two indexes running, the 'i' in the "for loop" and the 'j' in the "if loop", but only one is iterating correctly.
Sorry for the long post, and probably very poor formatting, I wanted to put as much information in as possible, but couldn't find the tools to post the data sets plainly.  I hope they're are not too odious to look at.

Comment: please use `dput()` on your data set and post the result here to make it reproducible. also, what is your desired output?

Comment: coding aficionados means 'those who love coding'?

Comment: What is a `if loop`?

Comment: Thanks for the reformatting Nicola, very grateful, reads much better, would love to know how you did it.  Is this the dput() command that epo3 suggested?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the key to your computation is to *find* the bracketing `Blanks` in time for each row in `Mdat_samp`. This is the meaning of your variable `j` which is the row index to `Blanks` for the lower bound of this bracket. You can compute this `j` for all rows of `Mdat_samp` for which this bracket exists in "vectorized" fashion. That is, without looping, which also makes this computation faster.

First, we assume that the data in `Blanks` is sorted in `Date/Time` in ascending order. In addition, we assume that the column `Date/Time` in both `Blanks` and `Mdat_samp` is of a Date-Time class such as `POSIXct`. If not, we can convert from characters using:

```
Blanks$`Date/Time` <- as.POSIXct(Blanks$`Date/Time`, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
Mdat_samp$`Date/Time` <- as.POSIXct(Mdat_samp$`Date/Time`, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Note that we have to put the column name in back-quotes because of the special character `/`.

Now, to compute `j`:

```
prevBlank <- expand.grid(Mdat_samp$`Date/Time`, Blanks$`Date/Time`)
nextBlank <- expand.grid(Mdat_samp$`Date/Time`, c(Blanks$`Date/Time`[2:nrow(Blanks)],NA))
j <- which(matrix(prevBlank$Var1 > prevBlank$Var2 & 
                  nextBlank$Var1 <= nextBlank$Var2,nrow=nrow(Mdat_samp)),
           arr.ind=TRUE)[,2]
```

We first create two data frames called `prevBlank` and `nextBlank` using `expand.grid`. Each of these enumerates all combinations of `Date/Time` from `Mdat_samp` and `Blanks` so that the bracketing condition can be evaluated for each row in `Mdat_samp` in vectorized fashion. The data frame `prevBlank` contains all combinations of `Date/Time` from `Mdat_samp` in its `Var1` column and `Blanks` in its `Var2` column ordered first by the rows in `Mdat_samp`. Similarly, the data frame `nextBlank` contains all combinations of `Date/Time` from `Mdat_samp` in its `Var1` column and the `Date/Time` column from `Blanks` shifted up by 1 (i.e., lead) in its `Var2` column. Note that we pad the shifted column with `NA` so that the resulting data frames, `prevBlank` and `nextBlank`, are the same size.

The expression `prevBlank$Var1 > prevBlank$Var2 & nextBlank$Var1 <= nextBlank$Var2` returns a boolean vector that is `TRUE` if the `Mdat_samp` `Date/Time` is between two adjoining `Blank` `Date/Time`s. Reshaping this vector into a matrix with the same number of rows as `Mdat_samp`, you will see that for each row, which corresponds to a row in `Mdat_samp`, there is **at most one** column that is `TRUE`:

```
matrix(prevBlank$Var1 > prevBlank$Var2 & 
       nextBlank$Var1 <= nextBlank$Var2,nrow=nrow(Mdat_samp))
##       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
## [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [6,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [7,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [8,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [9,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##[10,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##[11,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##[12,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##[13,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##[14,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##[15,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##[16,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##[17,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##[18,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##[19,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##[20,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##[21,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##[22,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##[23,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##[24,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##[25,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##[26,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
##[27,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
##[28,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
##[29,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
##[30,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
##[31,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
##[32,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
##[33,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
##[34,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA
##[35,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA
##[36,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA
##[37,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA
##[38,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA
```

The index of that column is the row index of `Blanks` that is the lower bound of the `Date/Time` bracket. We extract that index using `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` to return a matrix index (row, col), from which we extract the column index by subset (i.e., `[,2]` at the end). Note that the returned `j` is a vector so that this computes the bracketing `Date/Time` for all rows of `Mdat_samp` in vectorized fashion without need of a loop over the rows of `Mdat_samp`.

Note that if there is no bracket for a row in `Mdat_samp` (i.e., the `Date/Time` of the row in `Msamp_dat` is outside the range of `Date/Time` in `Blanks`), then all the results will be `FALSE` or `NA` for that row. In this case, there will be **no** entry for that row in `j`. Therefore, the entries in `j` corresponds to the rows in `Msamp_dat` whose `Date/Time` is in the range of the `Date/Times` in `Blanks`, which can be found by:

```
update.rows <- which(Mdat_samp$`Date/Time` > Blanks$`Date/Time`[1] &
                     Mdat_samp$`Date/Time` <= Blanks$`Date/Time`[nrow(Blanks)])
```

With `j` computed as above, your interpolation logic can also proceed in vectorized fashion:

```
divisor<-(as.double(difftime(Blanks[j+1, 2], Blanks[j,2]))-as.double(difftime(Blanks[j+1,2], Mdat_samp[update.rows,2])))/as.double(difftime(Blanks[j+1, 2], Blanks[j,2])) 
adjust<- (Blanks[j, 4:20]+(Blanks[j+1, 4:20]*divisor))
result <- Mdat_samp[update.rows,4:20]-adjust
```

Note that we are only able to adjust the rows of `Mdat_samp` in `update.rows`.

With your posted data:

```
print(head(result[1:8]))
##     Li(ppb)  Mg(ppb)  Ca(ppm)      Cr(ppb)   Mn(ppb)     Co(ppb)   Ni(ppb)   Cu(ppb)
##1  -0.00149062 111.0865 31.27917  1.051167618 0.1211668  0.91000000 0.1581676 0.1331660
##2   0.04099062 216.5730 41.16833  5.097332382 0.4913332  4.65400000 0.2963324 0.5313340
##3   0.09150000 303.8595 48.89750  9.698500000 1.2155000  9.33200000 0.4905000 1.2915000
##4   0.28000938 391.7460 57.00667 14.064667618 4.9036668 14.10000000 0.7086676 5.0966660
##5   0.53449062 474.1325 64.34583 29.565832382 9.6218332 30.05000000 0.9138324 9.9808340
##6   0.11289989 141.7515 33.47318  0.010453940 0.7148184  0.02009079 0.1207263 0.1948184
##7   0.10579978 131.2841 38.08137  0.004907880 0.5906368  0.01418158 0.1144526 0.1286368
##8   0.16773341 207.9163 52.52954  0.006364040 0.8434544  0.02127281 0.1621825 0.1744544
##9   0.12163330 152.0488 38.62773  0.000817980 0.6582728  0.01636360 0.1269088 0.2642728
##10  0.17353319 203.8814 54.27591  0.004271920 1.3110912  0.02345438 0.1826351 0.4110912
##11  0.15543307 180.9139 51.43410  0.005725860 0.7009097  0.02054517 0.1733614 0.2899097
##12  0.13931609 149.7466 38.53229  0.010178690 0.5957285  0.01663574 0.1300859 0.2167285
##13  0.13423285 132.0790 34.70047  0.004633740 0.6785465  0.01472675 0.1228140 0.2425465
##14  0.16614961 209.3114 48.13864  0.017088790 1.2293645  0.02081776 0.1685421 0.3633645
##15  0.18906637 192.2438 56.80682  0.035543840 0.8241825  0.02490877 0.2032701 0.3971825
##16  0.12544893 204.3643 49.04000  0.011816973 1.0750908  0.02209085 0.1659085 0.4789092
##17  0.09089785 140.1715 38.70000  0.016633946 0.8851817  0.01718170 0.1408170 0.3098183
##18  0.10634678 133.6788 40.90000  0.012450920 0.6492725  0.02027255 0.1467255 0.2017275
##19  0.11979570 149.3861 40.84000  0.011267893 0.7123634  0.01936339 0.1436339 0.1966366
##20  0.14624463 155.3933 43.08000  0.007084866 0.8684542  0.02045424 0.1515424 0.2895458
##21  0.14171416 157.9006 43.01000  0.034906271 0.8055453  0.01954531 0.1584531 0.2504547
##22  0.15616308 156.8079 44.92000  0.055723244 0.8316362  0.02163616 0.1733616 0.2423638
##23  0.18463262 171.1152 49.02000  0.027544649 1.1137272  0.02172723 0.1802723 0.2232728
##24  0.20208154 163.9224 49.47000  0.040361622 1.5538181  0.02381808 0.1781808 0.7321819
##25  0.16153047 131.6297 36.19000  0.015178595 1.5769089  0.01690893 0.1270893 0.8350911
##26  0.10064935 139.5850 36.40000  0.016663961 0.5380000  0.01911093 0.1331109 0.3332219
##27  0.17132468 172.9900 55.53000  0.020331981 0.6900000  0.02622213 0.1962221 0.2524443
##28  0.14300000 193.8950 44.01000  0.025000000 0.7810000  0.02133333 0.1513333 0.2686667
##29  0.17567532 181.6000 51.98000  0.053668019 0.7630000  0.02744453 0.1834445 0.3198891
##30  0.19535065 182.6050 53.05000  0.035336039 0.6770000  0.02555574 0.1905557 0.2981115
##31  0.15202597 147.7100 39.68000  0.040004058 0.7020000  0.01866694 0.1456669 0.2403339
##32  0.17570130 181.5150 41.83000  0.062672078 0.7900000  0.02777814 0.1677781 0.6045563
#333  0.16237662 124.4200 31.92000  0.061340097 0.5970000  0.01688934 0.1148893 0.2657787
```

where I print only the first `8` columns. Note that only 33 of the 38 rows of `Mdat_samp` is interpolated since last `5` have timestamps that exceed the range of `Blanks`.